# How could I define an application method on an S3 object in R? (like a "function object" in c++)

Tags: r, function, methods, r-s3

The problem I am trying to tackle here is needing to apply (execute) an S3 object which is essentially a vector-like structure.  This may contain various formulas which at some stage I need to evaluate for a single argument, in order to get back a vector-like object of the original shape, containing the evaluation of its constituent formulas at the given argument.

Examples of this (just to illustrate) might be a matrix of transformation - say rotation - which would take the angle to rotate by, and produce a matrix of values by which to multiply a point, for the given rotation.  Another example might be the vector of states in a problem in classical mechanics.  Then given *t*, *v*, *a*, etc, it could return *s*...

Now, I have created my container object in S3, and its working fine in most respects, using generic methods;  I also found the Ops.myClass system of operator overloading very useful.

To complete my class, all I need now is a way to specify it as executable.
I see that there are various mechanisms that will do what I want in part, for instance I suppose that `as.function()` will convert the object to behave as I want, and something like `lapply()` could be used for the "reverse" application of the argument to the functions.  What I am not sure how to do is link it all up so that I can do something like this mock-up:

```
new_Object <- function(<all my function vector stuff spec>)
vtest <- new_Object(<say, sin, cos, tan>)
vtest(1)
   ==>
myvec(.8414709848078965 .5403023058681398 1.557407724654902)
```

(Yes, I have already specified a generic `print()` routine that will make it appear nice)

All suggestions, sample code, links to examples are welcome.

PS =====

I have added some basic example code as per request.
I am not sure how much would be too much, so the full working minimal example, including operator overloading is in this [gist here](https://gist.github.com/alexgian/100f89dbda67073e1f886c6da063560f).

I am only showing the constructor and helper functions below:

```
# constructor
new_Struct <- function(stype , vec){
  stopifnot(is.character(stype)) # enforce up | down
  stopifnot(is.vector(vec))
  structure(vec,class="Struct", type=stype)
}

# constructor helper functions --- need to allow for nesting!
up <-function(...){
  vec <- unlist(list(...),use.names = FALSE)
  new_Struct("up",vec)
}
down <-function(...){
  vec <- unlist(list(...),use.names = FALSE)
  new_Struct("down",vec)
}
```

The above code behaves thus:

```
> u1 <- up(1,2,3)
> u2 <- up(3,4,5)
> d1 <- down(u1)
> d1
[1] down(1, 2, 3)
> u1+u2
[1] up(4, 6, 8)
> u1+d1
Error: '+' not defined for opposite tuple types
> u1*d1
[1] 14
> u1*u2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    5
[2,]    6    8   10
[3,]    9   12   15
> u1^2
[1] 14
> s1 <- up(sin,cos,tan)
> s1
[1] up(.Primitive("sin"), .Primitive("cos"), .Primitive("tan"))
> s1(1)
Error in s1(1) : could not find function "s1"
```

What I need, is for it to be able to do this:

```
> s1(1)
[1] up(.8414709848078965 .5403023058681398 1.557407724654902)
```

Comment: Please create a proper minimal reproducible example and show exactly what you expect as a return value. Your terminology is a bit off, e.g., we don't "specify [something] as executable" in R.

Comment: @Roland - Thanks for suggestion, and not least for creating r-S3 tag!  (Yes, I did not mean "amazon-S3", it got filled in automatically!).  I have now included  some code above.  Sorry about the terminology being "a bit off", it's only my fourth day with R.  I am not even sure there *is* any terminology, in other contexts I have heard speak of "applicable containers", "applicable structures", "object functions" or "executable vectors".  What would something like that be called in R, anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You can not call each function in a list of functions without a loop.

I'm not fully understanding all requirements, but this should give you a start:

```
new_Struct <- function(stype , vec){
  stopifnot(is.character(stype)) # enforce up | down
  stopifnot(is.vector(vec) || is.function(vec))
  structure(vec,class="Struct", type=stype)
}

# constructor helper functions --- need to allow for nesting!
up <- function(...) UseMethod("up")

up.default <- function(...){
  vals <- list(...)
  stopifnot(all(vapply(vals, is.vector, FUN.VALUE = logical(1))))
  vec <- unlist(vals, use.names = FALSE)
  new_Struct("up",vec)
}

up.function  <- function(...){
  funs <- list(...)
  stopifnot(all(vapply(funs, is.function, FUN.VALUE = logical(1))))
  new_Struct("up", function(x) new_Struct("up", sapply(funs, do.call, list(x))))
}

up(1, 2, 3)
#[1] 1 2 3
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "Struct"
#attr(,"type")
#[1] "up"

up(1, 2, sin)
#Error in up.default(1, 2, sin) : 
#  all(vapply(vals, is.vector, FUN.VALUE = logical(1))) is not TRUE 

up(sin, 1, 2)
#Error in up.function(sin, 1, 2) : 
#  all(vapply(funs, is.function, FUN.VALUE = logical(1))) is not TRUE 

s1 <- up(sin, cos, tan)
s1(1)
#[1] 0.8414710 0.5403023 1.5574077
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "Struct"
#attr(,"type")
#[1] "up"
```

Comment: Thanks for all the trouble you're taking, it's given me some ideas.  However, we're still not there, yet - you are changing the object between a vector and a function, according to the dispatch.  The object must always be a vector, albeit a "callable" one.  I have submitted an answer of my own (which I'm not accepting, it's a make-do), maybe what I want will be clearer from that.

Comment: That simply doesn't exist in R.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought I have come up with a way to approach this, it's not perfect, it would be great if someone could figure out a way to make the function call implicit/transparent.

So, for now I just use the `call()` mechanism on the object, and that seems to work fine.  Here's the pertinent part of the code, minus checks.  I'll put up the latest full version on the [same gist](https://gist.github.com/alexgian/100f89dbda67073e1f886c6da063560f) as above.

```
# constructor
new_Struct <- function(stype , vec){
  stopifnot(is.character(stype)) # enforce up | down
  stopifnot(is.vector(vec))
  structure(vec,class="Struct", type=stype)
}

# constructor helper functions --- need to allow for nesting!
up <- function(...){
  vec <- unlist(list(...), use.names = FALSE)
  new_Struct("up",vec)
}
down <- function(...){
  vec <- unlist(list(...), use.names = FALSE)
  new_Struct("down",vec)
}

# generic print for tuples
print.Struct <- function(s){
  outstr <- sprintf("%s(%s)", attributes(s)$type, paste(c(s), collapse=", "))
  print(noquote(outstr))
}

# apply the structure - would be nice if this could be done *implicitly*
call <- function(...) UseMethod("call")
call.Struct <- function(s,x){
  new_Struct(attributes(s)$type, sapply(s, do.call, list(x)))
}
```

Now I can do:

```
> s1 <- up(sin,cos,tan)
> length(s1)
[1] 3
> call(s1,1)
[1] up(0.841470984807897, 0.54030230586814, 1.5574077246549)
>
```

Not as nice as my ultimate target of

```
> s1(1)
[1] up(0.841470984807897, 0.54030230586814, 1.5574077246549)
```

but it will do for now...